# Representing JSON data in relational database table

Tags: database

I have a problem where I need to convert a JSON payload into SQL tables, while maintaining the relationships established in the payload. This is so that later I have the ability to query the tables and recreate the JSON payload structure in the future.

For example:

```
{
    "batchId": "batch1",
    "payees" : [
        { 
         "payeeId": "payee1",
         "payments": [
                {
                    "paymentId": "paymentId1",
                    "amount": 200,
                    "currency": "USD"
                },
                {
                    "paymentId": "paymentId2",
                    "amount": 200,
                    "currency": "YEN"
                },
                {
                    "paymentId": "paymentId2",
                    "amount": 200,
                    "currency": "EURO"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

For the above payload, I have a batch with payments grouped by payees. At its core it all boils down to a batch and its payments. But in that you can have groupings, for example above, it's grouped by payees.

One thing to note is that the payload may not necessarily always follow the above structure. Instead of grouping by `payees`, it could be by something else like `currency` for example. Or even no grouping at all, just a root level `batch` and an array of `payments`.

I want to know if there are conventions/rules I can follow to approach represent such data into relational tables? Thanks.

edit:

I am primarily looking to use Postgres and have looked into the jsonb feature that it provides for storing json data. However, I'm still struggling to figure out how/where (in terms of which table) to best store the grouping info.

Comment: you need batch table one to many with need payees table one to many payments, however its impossible to create a common structure when you say payload changes, you need more descriptive of the changes you need and i dont need to say that you can't create dynamic tables

Comment: I wonder if there's a way to store just the batch and payment data (which will always be there) and then find a way to store the grouping information separately. I know in postgres, there's something called jsonb that allows json data storage in column. Could that be leveraged here somehow?

Comment: what DB you use, many modern DB's has this feature, but you havent even mention wht type of a DB you work with

Comment: I'm looking to use postgres